# How to replace a pattern for all occurrences after a given line using Bash?

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I have been using `sed -i "" "s/pattern/replacement/g" file.txt` to replace pattern all over my file, but my goal is to do it for all the occurrences after the third line. I managed to do it using,

```
sed -n -e '3,$p' file.txt > aux
cat aux | sed "s/pattern/replacement/gI" > file.txt ,
```

but I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do it, preferably without using an auxiliary file (`aux`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "address range" before the substitution:

```
sed -e '3,$ s/pattern/replacement/gI'
```

If you want to remove the first two lines, you can use `tail`

```
sed ... | tail -n +3
```

or you can tell `sed` to remove them:

```
sed -e '1,2d' -e '3,$ s/pattern/replacement/gI'
```

Comment: I still want both the first lines so `sed -i "" -e "3,$ s/pattern/replacement/gI" file.text` works smooth. Tyvm :D